# Replace column values within a groupby and condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that I want to find the minimum value of a column within a group, and then based on that row, update the values of some of the other columns.

The following code does what I want:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2,],
                   'Albedo': [0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1],
                   'Temp' : [20, 30, 15, 40, 10, 5],
                   'Precip': [200, 100, 150, 60, 110, 45],
                   'Year': [1950, 2000, 2004, 1999, 1976, 1916]})

#cols to replace values for
cols = ['Temp', 'Precip', 'Year']

final = pd.DataFrame()


for key, grp in df.groupby(['ID']):

    #minimum values based on year
    replace = grp.loc[grp['Year'] == grp['Year'].min()]

    #replace the values
    for col in cols:
        grp[col] = replace[col].unique()[0]  

    #append the values
    final = final.append(grp)
print(final)
```

which yields:

```
   Albedo  ID  Precip  Temp  Year
0     0.2   1     200    20  1950
1     0.4   1     200    20  1950
2     0.5   1     200    20  1950
3     0.3   2      45     5  1916
4     0.5   2      45     5  1916
5     0.1   2      45     5  1916
```

so within each group from `ID` I find the minimum `Year` and then update `Temp`, `Precip` and the `Year` of the other rows.  This seems like a lot of looping and I am wondering if there is a better way though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` on `ID` + `transform` + `idxmin` on `Year` to get a series of indices. Pass these indices to `loc` to get your result.

```
(df.iloc[df.groupby('ID')['Year'].transform('idxmin')]
   .reset_index(drop=True)
   .assign(Albedo=df['Albedo']))

   Albedo  ID  Precip  Temp  Year
0     0.2   1     200    20  1950
1     0.4   1     200    20  1950
2     0.5   1     200    20  1950
3     0.3   2      45     5  1916
4     0.5   2      45     5  1916
5     0.1   2      45     5  1916
```

Comment: if I want to assign two columns how would I change it?  e.g. `df.iloc[idx].reset_index(drop=True).assign(Albedo=df.Albedo, Temp=df.Temp)`

Comment: @StefanoPotter That's how you'd do it, yes.

Comment: @StefanoPotter Alternatively, pass a dict: `.assign(**{'Albedo' : df.Albedo, 'Temp' : df.Temp})`... quite useful if you need to build a dict comp.