# Replace values within a groupby based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142757/replace-column-values-within-a-groupby-and-condition) but I'm still not seeing how I can apply the answer to my problem. I have a DataFrame like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2001-01-01', '2001-02-01', '2001-03-01', '2001-04-01', '2001-02-01', '2001-03-01', '2001-04-01'],
    'cohort': ['2001-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-02-01', '2001-02-01', '2001-02-01'],
    'val': [100, 101, 102, 101, 200, 201, 201]
})

df
    date        cohort      val
0   2001-01-01  2001-01-01  100
1   2001-02-01  2001-01-01  101
2   2001-03-01  2001-01-01  102
3   2001-04-01  2001-01-01  101
4   2001-02-01  2001-02-01  200
5   2001-03-01  2001-02-01  201
6   2001-04-01  2001-02-01  201
```

Grouping for each `cohort`, I want to replace the values of `val` with the maximum value of `val`, but only for observations where `date` is less than the `date` associated with the maximum value of `val`. So rows 0, 1, and 4 would be changed to look like this:

```
df #This is what I want my final df to look like 
    date        cohort      val
0   2001-01-01  2001-01-01  102
1   2001-02-01  2001-01-01  102
2   2001-03-01  2001-01-01  102
3   2001-04-01  2001-01-01  101
4   2001-02-01  2001-02-01  201
5   2001-03-01  2001-02-01  201
6   2001-04-01  2001-02-01  201
```

How can I do this without lots of loops?

Comment: Not sure I follow. For the second row, 2001-02-01 is greater than 2001-01-01, so why is val replaced for that row too?

Comment: The second row changes because the `date` is less than the date associated with the maximum value of `val`.

Comment: You mean per group or across the entire DataFrame?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Determine the maximum value of `val` PER GROUP of `cohort`
2. Determine the maximum date associated with `val`
3. Perform vectorised comparison and replacement with `np.where`

```
v = df.groupby('cohort').val.transform('max')
df['val'] = np.where(
    df.date <= df.set_index('cohort').val.idxmax(), v, df.val
)
```

```
df
    date        cohort      val
0   2001-01-01  2001-01-01  102
1   2001-02-01  2001-01-01  102
2   2001-03-01  2001-01-01  102
3   2001-04-01  2001-01-01  101
4   2001-02-01  2001-02-01  201
5   2001-03-01  2001-02-01  201
6   2001-04-01  2001-02-01  201
```